# Color picker in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

how to do [this](https://jsfiddle.net/3nv2ga4o/) in Vue.js? I don't want to use any components, can it be done in pure Vue.js?

I want to have only what's in the example after clicking the button. Just a color palette and opacity settings.

Actual code:

```
<!-- Input -->
<input type="text" v-model="color.navigation.background" maxlenght="7" placeholder="#000000">
<!-- Default color -->
<input type="button" @click="color.navigation.background = '#00CED1'">
<!-- Change color button -->
<input type="color" v-model="color.navigation.background">

var app = new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   data: {
    // Colors
    color: {
        // Navigation
        navigation: {
            background: '#00CED1'
        }
    }
}
```

})

Due to the **type="color"** it doesn't show exactly what I want and the color changes after clicking OK. Next, I want to remove # from the HEX value from the input.

Thanks!